# Programmatically routing after login in React

Tags: reactjs, redirect, router

I am new in React and I was trying to route the authenticated user to the main page. Unfortunately the user remains on the login page, although he logged in successfully. Here the relevant snippet of main.js which handles the routing part.

```
render(){
const {user} = this.props
{console.log("Logged in user: " + JSON.stringify(this.props.user.email))}
{console.log("Logged in : " + JSON.stringify(this.props.user.loggedIn))}
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (

  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    this.props.user.loggedIn === true
      ? <Component {...props} />

      : <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/login',

        }} />
  )} />
)  

<BrowserRouter>
<main>

  <Button icon='log out' floated='right' color='blue' onClick={()=>this.userLogout(user)}/>
  <Switch>

    <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={withRouter(StudentsMain)}/>

    <Route exact path='/about' component={About}/>
    <Route exact path='/login' component={withRouter(Login)}/>
    <PrivateRoute exact path='/settings' component={withRouter(Settings)}/>
    <PrivateRoute exact path='/assessment/:id' component={Assessment}/>
  </Switch>
</main>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And here the relevant part of the login component...

```
onValidSubmit = (formData) => {
console.log("logging in")

this.props.logInUser(formData)
this.setState({loggedIn: true})
};
```

onFormInfo = () => {
    this.setState({
      showInfo:true
    })
  }

```
.....
render(){

if (this.state.loggedIn === true) {
  console.log('Redirecting to Main Page')
  return <Redirect to='/' />
}
```

Perhaps somebody can give me a hint, why the user remains on the login page. If I change the url in the browser manually the routing works as expected. Thanks, Arnold

Comment: You need to keep track of the logged in state in the parent component (main? it's unclear), so that changing it triggers a re-render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should lift the state up so that you'll trigger a re-render in the right place. In this example, you can see the difference between triggering the state in different places.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class Child extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loggedIn: false,
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({ loggedIn: !this.state.loggedIn })
  }

  render() {
    return <p onClick={this.props.onClick || this.toggle}>I am {this.state.loggedIn ? 'in' : 'out'}</p>
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    loggedIn: false,
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({ loggedIn: !this.state.loggedIn })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Child onClick={this.toggle} />
        <Child />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qrtywg) is a live example.